# Popular question about C and malloc

Tags: discussion

I just had my WTF-moment for today when I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52570410/754705) about C and malloc. It has 3 upvotes, 1 downvote, and 8 detailed answers. One person favourited the question.

I think this question deserves to be deleted, or at least to be downvoted and closed. Someone who asks such question will probably not understand the very detailed answers either.

It reminded me somehow of that guy who figured out why people buy Crocs, and who used that knowledge for a political campaign (not sure if you heard about it in the US, but we have heard it in Europe). I don't think that anyone here had bad intentions, but I really don't understand why this question attracts so many answers, and so many upvotes to itself and to its answers.

Is it just me? Is this really a good, on-topic, question, that deserves to be upvoted and answered by quite a few very-high-rep-users? And I don't understand why all the answers are upvoted either. Some have even more than one upvote. Do they upvote each other? Do we want more of these kind of questions and answers on this site? I cannot close-vote though, because I don't find a good close-reason in the list.

Comment: It's a crazy question, almost certainly a homework dump, and most of the answers are high-rep cucumbers.  This is why I don't bother much with curating SO any more - it's just a pointless waste of time.

Comment: @Michael: I think it's odd to call this question "popular". It's only got 49 views (and that's after being seen by several people on Meta who probably would not have seen it had it not been for your post here). It only has a net +3. And so forth.

Comment: All questions about linked lists in C and C++ must be dupes a hundred times over, are always a waste of space, and always get lots of answers.

Comment: It is a crystal-clear question that everybody knows the answer to.  Contributors to the [c] tag don't get that very often.  Especially on Saturday, you can practically hear them exclaiming *finally!* :)

Comment: @HansPassant: maybe someone should ask *"What does `int banana = 22+2;` mean? Is it better style to write `int banana = 24;` instead?` What is the difference between these two statements?"*. That is also a crystal-clear question ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this a good question? No. It can only be asked by someone who doesn't really understand what those statements are doing. You don't even have to know what `malloc` is doing outside of returning a value. So long as you know what `NULL` is, and what assignment to a variable means, then it's no more difficult to reason about than `int i = 5 + 8; i = 0;`.

Such a question is not likely to help other users because of the lack of foundational understanding. There are innumerable ways to phrase this lack of understanding, so a search based on one form will not find it. And its highly unlikely that users will remember this question to use as a dupe target for such questions.

But, we have no valid close reason for such questions. "Too localized" was removed long ago due to frequent misuse.

Such questions get answered because... well, answering them is easy. Everyone with even a modicum of knowledge of C can tell this person what their misunderstanding is. It's no different from the "[Bikeshed effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality)".

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any rationale for *closing* the question.

- It's on-topic.
- It's clear what's being asked.
- It's objective and there's a narrow focus to it.

I also don't see any rationale for *deletion*, either.

- It's not offensive, harmful or detrimental.
- It's not actively harming anyone else.

If you don't like it, then downvote it.  But honestly, the question reads objectively on-topic to me.

Specifically to this point:

> Someone who asks such question will probably not understand the very detailed answers either.

Two things to that:  it's unfair to make that assumption of an asker, and it's unreasonable to expect that we'd hand-hold them through the answer, either.  Experts or enthusiasts in C who understand the question would be able to explain the answer to the OP in a way they understand.

Comment: It's a crazy question.  It gies two options, neither are useful, but only one utterly ridiculous.

Comment: @MartinJames:  Yes, but I like many other reviewers lack the prerequisite knowledge to determine that.  The question is *otherwise* on topic, but it's incredulous or poor by your (and others') determination.  Then that means you should downvote it.  Meta doesn't need to get involved.